# CTRL acts as ESC on my xfce desktop?

Tags: linux, keyboard-shortcuts, input

I'm pretty new to linux, and usually I know how to Google my way into answers (typically on here or StackOverflow), but I can't find anything on this, maybe because the peculiarity of the search term.

For whatever reason, tapping <kbd>LCtrl</kbd> on its own inputs simultaneously as <kbd>LCtrl</kbd>+<kbd>Esc</kbd>. Holding <kbd>LCtrl</kbd>, or holding another key before pressing <kbd>LCtrl</kbd> only registers as <kbd>LCtrl</kbd>. I don't want this functionality, I would rather <kbd>LCtrl</kbd> act only as <kbd>LCtrl</kbd>. Whenever I try to search for this, I only can find people asking how to do this, not vice versa.

Trying to look into this, I found people asking for windowing systems etc, and so I'm not sure what info is relevant (again, new to this) but I'm using XFCE/XFCM4. I have xcape installed to trigger the whisper menu, but to my understanding it doesn't come with preconfigured macros or anything.

Let me know if I failed to mention anything, otherwise, thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: hello and welcome to unix.se.  You may find an answer here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/537835/27616  (I just googled: `xfce ctrl`and it lead me directly to it)